# Как сделать у Label прозрачный backColor - winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, label

я написал код на создания label и сделал задний фон прозрачным но на деле он просто чорный .

```cs
 using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp11
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var lb = new Label
            {
                BackColor = Color.Transparent,
                Text = "X",
                Location = new Point(10 , 10),
                ForeColor = Color.Black
            };
            this.Controls.Add(lb);
        }
    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Установите ему например зелёный фон, и задайте маску прозрачности на зелёный. https://stackoverflow.com/a/4387762/9630063

Comment: Нужно больше данных о контексте. На какой контрол добавляется лейбл? `-48` - ???

Comment: на основной - Controls

Comment: Не воспроизводится. Приведите больше кода.

Comment: Повторяю ещё раз: описанное вами поведение не воспроизводится. Назначение `Color.Transparent` должно работать. Вы явно ошиблись в чём-то другом. Вы задаёте координату `-48` - в итоге лейбл должен быть за пределами родительского контрола. Покажите **больше кода**.

Comment: обновил код . теперь там весь мой код из проекта .

Comment: Покажите ещё файл Form1.Designer.cs